# Validation works when you leave a space in the input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, react-native, validation

There are entries that need to be filled in, and those entries have validations. For example, if I talk about name validation; A user can have a first and middle name (I'm not talking about the user's last name). Validation does not work when the username is entered. No problem so far. However, when you leave a space and enter the middle name, the validation works. I don't want validation to run when I enter middle name after space. How can I do it?

**js**

```
const [nameValidationState, setNameValidationState] = useState({
  error: false,
  helperText: '',
});

const nameOnChange = (event) => {
  if (nameValidator(event.target.value)) {
    setNameValidationState({ error: false, helperText: '' });
    setPaymentInfo({
      ...paymentInfo,
      firstName: event.target.value,
    });
  } else {
    setNameValidationState({ error: true, helperText: 'Please enter your name.' });
    setPaymentInfo({
      ...paymentInfo,
      firstName: null,
    });
  }

const handleFirstNameChange = (event) => {
  nameOnChange(event);
  handleInputChange(event);
};
```

**validator**

```
export const nameValidator = (name) => {
  const nameRegex = /^[a-zA-ZwığüşöçĞÜŞÖÇİ]+$/;

  return nameRegex.test(name);
};
```

**html**

```
<AS.TextField
  placeholder=""
  onChange={handleFirstNameChange}
  error={nameValidationState.error}
  helperText={nameValidationState.helperText}
  name="firstName"
  value={paymentInfo.firstName}
/>
```

Comment: If you don't want to trigger the form validation on input change, trigger it on form submission.

Comment: I just want to be able to make a middle name after the space.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help you?

```
let text = " Middle Name"; // Starts with empty space

if(text.startsWith(" ")) { // Checks if it starts with empty space
   // TRUE
   // YOUR LOGIC
} else {
   // FALSE
   // YOUR LOGIC
}
```

EDIT: Here is a list of string methods you can do in javascript, it will interest you: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp